# show detail processlist like at mariadb on maxscale

Tags: mariadb, process, maxscale

on mariadb when i need check what are query is running or sleep on mariadb instance.
i can see with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or `select * information_schema.processlist`.

But after mariadb join and client connect to maxscale i can't see processlist like `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or `select * information_schema.processlist`

any advice ?

maxscale configuration

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto
max_auth_errors_until_block=0
admin_host=192.168.101.107
admin_port=8989
admin_enabled=1
```

Edit.
I already update paramater at maxscale configuration

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto
max_auth_errors_until_block=0
admin_host=192.168.101.107
admin_port=8989
admin_enabled=1
retain_last_statements=20
dump_last_statements=on_error
```

query already show from command

```
maxctrl show sessions
```

but there is query from last execution on each session. and i can't see the different like `sleep` or still running when i run command `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on mariadb.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only users with `PROCESS` privilege can see processes other than their own.

From the [SHOW PROCESSLIST Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html) (MySQL Documentation):

> `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows which threads are running. **If you have the `PROCESS` privilege, you can see all threads. Otherwise, you can see only your own threads** (that is, threads associated with the MySQL account that you are using). If you do not use the `FULL` keyword, only the first 100 characters of each statement are shown in the Info field.

And from [Privileges Provided by MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) (MySQL Documentation):

> Enables display of information about the threads executing within the server (that is, information about the statements being executed by sessions). The privilege enables use of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or **mysqladmin processlist** to see threads belonging to other accounts; you can always see your own threads. The `PROCESS` privilege also enables use of `SHOW ENGINE`.

Comment: I've added some meat to your answer. Hope you don't have any issues with the additional information?

Comment: i already using users with `PROCESS` privileges

Comment: @Johnakahot2use - Thanks for the links and quotes.

Comment: @febry - Let's see your Maxscale configuration.